# SumIf Importrange Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Hi I have this formula

```
=SUMIF('March 2024'!B$4:B$1000,A4,'March 2024'!I$4:I$1000)
```

Now the March 2024 tab is getting moved to a different spreadsheet. I tried using importrange function but it doesn't work

```
=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("URL","'March 2024'!B$4:B$1000"),A4,IMPORTRANGE("URL","'March 2024'!I$4:I$1000"))
```

What is the needed formula to make this work? Also a thing to note is A4 has this importrange formula which is working. Formula is shown below.

```
=unique(filter(IMPORTRANGE("URL","'March 2024'!B4:B"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","'March 2024'!B4:B")<>""))
```

Comment: it's better to create an "import" sheet where you import the whole tab and then use SUMIF referring to that tab.

Comment: Are you okay with alternative solutions like Google App Script and use it as a custom function?

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly due to latency issue. Please see [this](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/25676823/sumif-and-importrange-are-not-working-together?hl=en) article related to this issue.

However, assuming you are open to a different solution using Google sheets formula itself, you can do it by QUERY formula

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "'March 2024'!B$4:I$1000"),"SELECT SUM(Col8) where Col1 = "&A4)
```

I tried this and it worked for me.